# debug message printed on jupyter notebook... How to disable it

Tags: jupyter-notebook

When I am trying to use quandl to download some data within a function in jupiter notebook:

I got some debug messages like,

> 03-Jan-18 10:43:40 DEBUG     Starting new HTTPS connection (1):
>   www.quandl.com 03-Jan-18 10:43:40 DEBUG     https://www.quandl.com:443
>   "GET
>   /api/v3/datasets/SCF/CBOE_VX2_ON/data?order=asc&end_date=2100-11-17&start_date=2017-11-28
>   HTTP/1.1" 200 None

There are too much of them and i do not want to see them... what shall i do? Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this inside your notebook:

```
#Supress default INFO logging

import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
```

Comment: @user40780 please select it as an answer if it did what you wanted.